# What does the ">>=" operator do in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, bit-manipulation

I've seen this operator used in [one](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-3-percents-and-proportions-4db014e080b1) of Mikhail Vladimirov's articles:

```
function mostSignificantBit(uint x) public pure returns (uint r) {
    require (x > 0);
    if (x >= 2**128) { x >>= 128; r += 128; }
    if (x >= 2**64) { x >>= 64; r += 64; }
    if (x >= 2**32) { x >>= 32; r += 32; }
    if (x >= 2**16) { x >>= 16; r += 16; }
    if (x >= 2**8) { x >>= 8; r += 8; }
    if (x >= 2**4) { x >>= 4; r += 4; }
    if (x >= 2**2) { x >>= 2; r += 2; }
    if (x >= 2**1) { x >>= 1; r += 1; }
}
```

What is the difference between the normal shift operator `>>` and `>>=`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`>>` and `<<` operators are the shift operators.

From [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#shifts):

> The result of a shift operation has the type of the left operand,
> truncating the result to match the type. Right operand must be
> unsigned type. Trying to shift by signed type will produce a
> compilation error.
>
> - For positive and negative `x` values, `x << y` is equivalent to `x * 2**y`.
> - For positive `x` values, `x >> y` is equivalent to `x / 2**y`.
> - For negative `x` values, `x >> y` is equivalent to `(x + 1) / 2**y - 1` (which is the same as dividing `x` by `2**y` while rounding down towards negative infinity).

But, `>>=` and `<<=` operators work like `+=` or `-=`.

- `x >>= 1` is equivalent to `x = x >> 1`.
- `x <<= 1` is equivalent to `x = x << 1`.